# How to troubleshoot and resolve 404 on SockJs's /info path when with cross-origin

Tags: websocket, cors, spring-websocket, sockjs

I'm having trouble with SockJs and CORS. I use spring. I set up the WebMvcConfigured as follows:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry
                    .addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                    .allowCredentials(true);
            ;
        }
    };
}
```

and WebSocketConfig as follows:

```
    @Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

However, when my web client tries to `GET` against `/gs-guide-websocket/info` , it gets a `404`.

SockJs's specification requires a `/info` path to be present. It seems like even though I did use `.withSockJS()` on the server side, it did not set up the `/gs-guide-websocket/info` path.

How should I create this path through `spring` and/or `spring-websocket`?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I am not using the STOMP protocol, whereas I have configured the websocket with SockJS which is working fine for me.

Here the message payload has sent as response to the frontend.

#### CustomWebSocketHandler.java

```
@Component
public class CustomWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        String payload = message.getPayload();
        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("message", "Session started");
        jsonObject.addProperty("payload", payload);
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(new Gson().toJson(jsonObject)));
    }   
}
```

#### WebSocketConfig.java

```
@EnableWebSocket
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private CustomWebSocketHandler customWebSocketHandler;
    
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {

        webSocketHandlerRegistry
            .addHandler(customWebSocketHandler, "/socket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS()
            .setHeartbeatTime(20);      
    }
}
```